# Mocking NLog4Net with NSubstitute and capturing parameters passed to log.ErrorFormat

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, fsi

Am trying to rewrite into F# the following C# which mocks up a Log4Net logger with NSubstitute and captures the parameters passed to a Log.ErrorFormat call into the _loggerException string.

```cs
string _loggerException = string.Empty;

this.c_logger.When(log => log.ErrorFormat(
    Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<string>()))
    .Do(logger => _loggerException = logger.Arg<string>().ToString());
```

The following is the F# I have reached

```
let mutable _loggerException = System.String.Empty

let _logger = Substitute.For<ILog>()

SubstituteExtensions.When(_logger, _logger.WarnFormat(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<string>())).Do(fun logger -> _loggerException <- logger.Arg<string>())
```

However I am getting an error on the second parameter to `SubstituteExtensions.When` - `_logger.WarnFormat(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<string>())` as follows:

> This expression was expected to have type `Action<ILog>` but here has type `unit`.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to me your `When` wants to take a function, but you give it the result of `WarnFormat`? You wanted to have a `fun logger -> logger.WarnFormat(...)` there?